# Trying to scrape images from reddit using their API and cURL

Tags: php, curl, reddit

I am pretty new to Php and I try to write some code that will scrape images from reddit.

Right off the bat I have a problem. When I execute this code reddit wants to confirm that I am over 18, which makes sense because its a NSFW subreddit. Not sure where to go from here.

Any input is appreciated, I am not looking for someone to copy/paste the required code I would like to learn, thank you!

The reason I am trying to login is so I can validate that I am over 18 automatically through my session.

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

$data = array('user' => 'xxxx', 'passwd' => 'xxxx', 'rem' => TRUE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.reddit.com/api/login');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'Cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'Cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_exec($ch);

$url = 'http://reddit.com/r/ass';

$page = file_get_contents($url);

var_dump($page);

?>
```

Comment: You are mixing two things here. The first part is using curl for the request, the second part is using `file_get_contents`. Technically  both can work, however, start with one of those, e.g. curl. If so then do `var_dump($post). Also the API is documented here: http://www.reddit.com/dev/api

Comment: Can you tell me if my thought process is correct:

Using cURL to connect and login, and then after I have logged in I am getting the contents of the $url under that login and then dumping the page which I will then parse.

PS I edited my code there was an error in it.

Comment: Using the cookiefile / jar with curl looks fine for the reddit API and the login method for the session cookie. But I'm not fluent with reddit API. So better get the code in order and actually test it. I think it won't hurt if you do a couple of "wrong" request to reddit API at all. Go for it.

Comment: should i use a multiple cURL? i think what is happening is that it is performing the curl, but then throwing it away and then going to the url to get contents without my cookie

Comment: multiple cUrl? That can mean a lot and different stuff, so I tend to just say: no idea what you mean, please elaborate - but please test before asking. I mean, you can have a thousand questions, but I can't answer them all for you. Take a look at the FAQ as well which kind of questions are welcomed here and checkout the how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Cool that username+password combination works! 58 link karma...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to retrieve a list of posts for a subreddit, you'll be better off by retrieving the list of posts formatted as JSON instead of the regular HTML. Postfix the URL to the subreddit with .json and decode it to PHP structures by using json_decode(). For an added bonus you won't need to confirm you're over 18 to retrieve the content.

[Example](http://www.reddit.com/r/aww.json)

This doesn't answer your question, but it solves your problem.

Comment: i know what you did fisk and thank you very much LOL